# MVVM with ReactiveCocoa: limit the text length of a UITextField in view model

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I'm adopting MVVM with ReactiveCocoa. Now I have a UITextField which I need to limit it's max text length to 100.

In my view:

```
- (void)bindViewModel
{
    RAC(self.viewModel, text) = self.textField.rac_textSignal;
    [RACObserve(self.viewModel, text) subscribeNext:(NSString *text) {
        self.textField.text = text;
    }];
}
```

In my view model

```
- (id)init
{
    [RACObserve(self, text) subscribeNext:^(NSString *x) {
        //block 1
        if (x.length > maxTextLength) {
            x = [x substringToIndex:maxTextLength];
        }
    }];
}
```

But this doesn't work, `block 1` is never called.

By using MVVM, I believe that the text length control logic should be put in my view model, but what is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: This answer might be helpful (it's not using MVVM, but you can modify it quite easily to do so): http://stackoverflow.com/a/23948331/2128900

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, because in MVVM, view model shouldn't have a reference to view which contains the text field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23948331/2128900): you can take `rac_textSignal` from the text field and use `map` to trim the string to the desired length. Then bind the mapped signal to the text field using `RAC` macro. 
As you noted, view model shouldn't have a reference to the view. But it can be passed a *signal* and return a mapped signal.

In a view:

```
RAC(self.textField, text) = [self.viewModel validatedTextWithSignal:self.deviceName.rac_textSignal];
```

in your view model:

```
- (RACSignal *)validatedTextWithSignal:(RACSignal *)signal {
    NSUInteger kMaxLength = 5;
    return [signal map:^id(NSString *text) {
        return text.length <= kMaxLength ? text : [text substringToIndex:kMaxLength];
    }];
}
```

This also makes the text control logic easy to test - in unit tests, you can pass something like `-[RACSignal return:@"foo"]` to the view model and check if the output is correct.

Comment: I got it, my understanding about RAC() was wrong, thank you.