# ReactiveCocoa: limit the input length of UITextfield but allow unlimited length when selecting characters

Tags: ios, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

When inputing text in Chinese, you input English characters and then select the Chinese characters, before you selecting the Chinese characters, the English characters are in a selected state(-markedRange).
Before using ReactiveCocoa, I can do it like this:

in `UITextField's UIControlEventEditingChanged` event callback:

```
    const NSUInteger limitLength = 10;
    NSString *tobeString = textField.text;
    UITextRange *selectedRange = [textField markedTextRange];
    BOOL nothingSelected = (selectedRange==nil || selectedRange.isEmpty);
    if (nothingSelected) {
        if (tobeString.length > addressItemNameLimitLength) {
            textField.text = [tobeString substringToIndex:limitLength];
        }
    }
    self.textField.text = textField.text;
```

But in `MVVM with ReactiveCocoa`, I can't get a reference to the `UITextField` in my `view model`, how can I get the `marked range` and `text` of the text field at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I consider logic of inputing Chinese characters as helper for user input, thus view model should not know about this.

Building on answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228116/mvvm-with-reactivecocoa-limit-the-text-length-of-a-uitextfield-in-view-model), you could do something like this:

In `UITextField` category add signal similar to `-rac_textSignal` except it won't fire if there is non-empty selected range during editing:

```
- (RACSignal *)textSignalForChineseInput {
    RACSignal* editingEventsSignal = [[[self rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged]
                                      filter:^BOOL(UITextField* x) {
                                          return x.selectedTextRange == nil || x.selectedTextRange.isEmpty;
                                      }]
                                      merge:[self rac_signalForControlEvents:(UIControlEventAllEditingEvents & ~UIControlEventEditingChanged)]];

    @weakify(self)
    return [[[[[RACSignal
        defer:^RACSignal *{
            @strongify(self)
            return [RACSignal return:self];
        }]
        concat:editingEventsSignal]
        map:^id(UITextField* x) {
            return x.text;
        }]
        takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal]
        setNameWithFormat:@"%@ -rac_textSignalForChineseInput", self.rac_description];
}
```

In a view:

```
RAC(self.textField, text) = [self.viewModel validatedTextWithSignal:self.deviceName.rac_textSignal];
```

In a view model:

```
- (RACSignal *)validatedTextWithSignal:(RACSignal *)signal {
    NSUInteger kMaxLength = 5;
    return [signal map:^id(NSString *text) {
        return text.length <= kMaxLength ? text : [text substringToIndex:kMaxLength];
    }];
}
```